# How to mock objects initialized in constructor using an external method call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

```
final HttpClient httpClient;

final HttpUtils httpUtils;

@Autowired
public SampleConstructor(HttpUtils httpUtils) {

    this.httpClient = ApacheHttpSingleton.getHttpClient();
    this.httpUtils = httpUtils;
}
```

So I have this class having two objects which I am initializing using the autowired constructor. While writing the JUnit tests for this class, I have to mock the two objects. The HttpUtils object is straightforward. However, it's the HttpClient object I am having trouble mocking.

```
@Mock
HttpUtils mockHttpUtils;

@Mock
HttpClient mockHttpClient;

@InjectMocks
SampleConstructor mockService;
```

The above approach works for HttpUtils but not for HttpClient. Can someone please help me with how I can inject the mocked object for HttpClient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a package-private constructor that takes both objects as its parameters. Place your unit test in the same package (but in src/test/java/) so it has access to that constructor. Send in mocks to that constructor:

```
final HttpClient httpClient;
final HttpUtils httpUtils;

@Autowired
public SampleConstructor(HttpUtils httpUtils) {
    this(ApacheHttpSingleton.getHttpClient(), httpUtils);
}

// For testing
SampleConstructor(HttpClient httpClient, HttpUtils httpUtils) {
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
    this.httpUtils = httpUtils;
}
```

Then in your test:

```
@Mock
HttpUtils mockHttpUtils;

@Mock
HttpClient mockHttpClient;

SampleConstructor c = new SampleConstructor(mockHttpClient, mockHttpUtils);
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. :) Didn't think of this way earlier.